# Zapier Webhooks and AJAX Requests

Tags: javascript, ajax, zapier

Is there a way of triggering Zapier webhooks from client-side applications?

I can't seem to make successful AJAX requests and always get:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://zapier.com/hooks/catch/..... 
The request was redirected to 'https://zapier.com/hooks/catch/..../', 
which is disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight.
```

Answer (score 9):

You must not modify the `Content-Type` header

https://zapier.com/help/create/code-webhooks/troubleshoot-webhooks-in-zapier#posting-json-from-web-browser-access-control-allow-headers-in-preflight-response-error

Answer (score 5):

As of January 15th, 2016, Zapier does not support catching a webhook using a POST request from a browser (due to CORS headers required for the browser's preflight request).

A GET request with query string values will work though.

Comment: There is any doc with this info?

Comment: Yes, GET request is allowed in browser. Also, You should not include the special headers to request header.

Answer (score 5):

Zapier does not support CORS. The way I got this to work was to use an image.

```
var newImage = new Image();
newImage.src = "https://zapier.com/hooks/catch/myhook?param=one";
```

or

```
<img height="0" width="0" src="https://zapier.com/hooks/catch/myhook?param=one">
```

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
  try {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "https://zapier.com/hooks/catch/myhook");
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify({data: "example"}));
    console.log("Pushed to Zapier successfully!");
  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a Fetch request without setting the `Content-Type` also works,

```
const response = await fetch(
`https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/${code}/${code}`,
    {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify(payload)
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

Zapier's awesome support team fixed CORS issue in under 24 hours!

Kudos Zapier!

Comment: how did they fixed it? I'm having the same issue?

Comment: https://zapier.com/help/create/code-webhooks/troubleshoot-webhooks-in-zapier#posting-json-from-web-browser-access-control-allow-headers-in-preflight-response-error